# Laravel 4 nginx servername/myappname

Tags: nginx, laravel, laravel-4

I try to make my production server to serve my applications in a same style as phpmyadmin is served. Like example.com/phpmyadmin and what I try to do is example.com/myappname.

My nginx/sites-available/default looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name _;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

        location /myapp {
                root /var/www/myapp/public/;
                index index.php;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }


        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

So if someone has a working conf for this, I would like to have it too!

Comment: Perhaps you can share what's working with your config?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your `/phpmyadmin` location has extra configuration to pass the request to PHP-FPM  via the `fast_cgi` configurations.

You'll need to do that for your `/myapp` location as well.

You may want to change your `myapp` location to something like this:

```
location ^/myapp/(.+\.php)$ {
    root /var/www/myapp/public/;
    index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

For comparison, here is my [Laravel nginx configuration](http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-12-04-lemp-nginx-setup) - however I don't have my app running under a "sub-directory".

Try changing some configuration items to see what you can get to work. Note that I removed `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` from the Laravel app location - I dont believe it is necessary.

Lastly, would this make more sense on ServerFault? You may get better answers there.